# SDL goes only with main and ignores the other .c and .h files i have in my program

Tags: c, gcc, cmd, sdl-2, mingw-w64

i'm trying to use SDL with my c project actualy it's a multi file project connected to each other so when i installed sdl i found a problem that sdl doesn't connect with other files it only connect with main and i find this error 
C:\Users\EYAOSM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoI9IBj.o:main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `lstcltcreer'
with all the functions i have outside of main in the other files

i used this to connect sdl to main

C:\Users\Eya Osmane\Desktop\prooooojjjjj>gcc src/*main.c -o bin/prog -I include -L lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

this is the structure of my program

src contains the main and the other files i wrote

and the other files bin include lib and obj are sdl files

and all these files are plased in projjjjj which is in my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with SDL.

You just need to pass to GCC the list of .c file your project uses. This can be done with the wildcard (*) operator.

`gcc src/*.c -o bin/prog -I include -L lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Or by explicitely including the files

`gcc src/a.c src/b.c src/main.c -o bin/prog -I include -L lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Comment: thank u very much it worked  and i dont fint the error anymore but i still have problem with it  because in code blocks there is indefined reference to sdl.h

Comment: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory